# Missing delimiting slash between hosts and options

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hello (I hope my English is not to bad) !

I'm actually trying to start a basic database with MongoDB atlas (the online alternative), but I cannot pass the first step : connecting! I've got always the same error :

> throw err;
>           ^
>
> Error: Missing delimiting slash between hosts and options
>       at parseConnectionString (C:\Users\Etudiant1\Documents\Cours\ProjetPerso\Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:164:11)
>       at parseHandler (C:\Users\Etudiant1\Documents\Cours\ProjetPerso\Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:129:14)
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\Etudiant1\Documents\Cours\ProjetPerso\Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:25:12)
>       at deprecated (internal/util.js:47:15)
>       at connect (C:\Users\Etudiant1\Documents\Cours\ProjetPerso\Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:180:3)
>       at connectOp (C:\Users\Etudiant1\Documents\Cours\ProjetPerso\Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:284:3)
>       at executeOperation (C:\Users\Etudiant1\Documents\Cours\ProjetPerso\Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:420:24)
>       at MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\Etudiant1\Documents\Cours\ProjetPerso\Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:168:10)
>       at Function.MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\Etudiant1\Documents\Cours\ProjetPerso\Bot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:372:22)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Etudiant1\Documents\Cours\ProjetPerso\Bot\testMongo.js:4:13)

I've already seen some similar error on stack overflow but I didn't find a solution for my problem. My code is as following :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var uri = "mongodb://Admin:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-shard-00-00-xm3ps.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xm3ps.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xm3ps.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true";
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
 // Paste the following examples here
  if(err){
     throw err;
} else {
     console.log("Connected");
}
db.close();
});
```

Thanks already !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Laura welcome to StackOverflow! I've included code and explanation below:

```
MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {

  if (err) {

    console.log("error connecting");

  } else {

    console.log("success connecting");
    //do something like insert,update,etc.

    db.close();

  }


});
```

1. It looks like you are missing useNewUrlParser: true
2. You will want to use db.close() method after you've performed an operation
3. For security purpose, you may not want to write out the URL explicitly, rather store as an environment variable and reference instead.

> var uri = process.env.mongoURI instead of var uri = mongodb://...

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my link problem ! And also thanks for the security advice, always a good practice to know !